# Member is not recognized or accessible WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

So I know this has been asked many times, I've read about 10 post with this issue. I've restarted Visual Studios and I'm still getting the error.

```
The Member IcoIcon is not recognized or accessible
```

Here is my code

```
 public partial class Icomoon : UserControl
    {

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IcoIconProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IcoIcon", typeof(string), typeof(Icomoon), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public object IcoIcon
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(IcoIconProperty);
            set => SetValue(IcoIconProperty, IcoMoonVariables.Invoke((string)value));
        }

        public Icomoon()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

So from what I can tell is I registered it properly, and it is showing up in the Intellisense when I type it out. But then it still gives me the error.

`<UserControl:Icomoon IcoIcon="LineGraph" />`

Am I overlooking a member's class names? I've been looking over this for some time so any sense of direction would be helpful. Suggestions appreciated

Comment: When declaring an element in XAML the string before the `:` is supposed to be the [NameSpace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-namespaces-and-namespace-mapping-for-wpf-xaml) where the class is declared. You have `UserControl:Icomoon`, is `UserControl` the label you gave to your namespace?

Comment: Yes it is the label

Comment: `UserControl:Icomoon` => `local:Icomoon`

Comment: I also see that your DependencyProperty is registered as a `string`, but the normal property is an `object`. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: Keith I had it originally an object then switched to string to see if that worked. I'll retry object for giggles.

Comment: @KeithStein `object` has `ToString`, doesn't matter in this case as it's a string.

Comment: Codexer I don't have a local. I separate most of the stuff for naming conventions. Ideas of constantly labeling local: button or local:resource etc. I have a few higher folders that I keep everything in to keep it clean and conventional. Just the way I like to do stuff

Comment: @EasyBB understand, the point already mentioned though is the namespace that control lives in, for testing, mine was local.

Comment: Copying your code into a new project doesn't give the same error on my end. Does the code run and work for you even though it's giving an error in Visual Studio?

Comment: Keith after trying to run it, it ran and the error went away... What is up with that?

Comment: Dumb question, did you do a clean & re-build? Sometimes those DP can be strange in UC...

Comment: Yeah cleaned solution and cleaned the build. Then rebuilt everything

Comment: So you rebuilt and the error was still there, but then you ran it and it went away? Go figure. Well, at least it's gone now.

Comment: yeah. of course, the programmer's way, when you fix one error two more arise.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Object` why not specify it as a value type through and through? A reference dependency property is different from a value one.

Since its a string, specify it as such and set the empty condition to `string.empty` *and not null* such as:

```
    #region public string IcoIcon

    public string IcoIcon
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(IcoIconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IcoIconProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the IcoIcon dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IcoIconProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "IcoIcon",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(MainWindow),
            new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
    #endregion public string IcoIcon
```